# Python - BeautifulSoup - For loop outputting data in wrong order

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape match data from the following site

https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/darts

The data is scraping without error but the output is not showing as expect. I believe it is due to me calling the for loop incorrectly (see code and output below)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def makesoup(url):
    cookies = {'mycountries' : '101,28,3,102,42,10,18,4,2'}
    r = requests.post(url,  cookies=cookies)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
   
    
def matchscrape(g_data):

    for match in g_data:

        scheduled = match.findAll('div', class_='main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs')
        details = match.findAll('div', class_='col-xs-6 mobile-normal')
        
        for schedule in scheduled:
           
            print("DateTimes; ", schedule.text.strip())
        for detail in details:
                print("Details:",  detail.text.strip())
            
            
def matches():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/darts")
    matchscrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "listData"}))
```

The above code provides the following output:

[image: incorrect output]

I then tried to alter the position of the for loop as per the code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def matchscrape(g_data):

    for match in g_data:

        scheduled = match.findAll('div', class_='main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs')
        details = match.findAll('div', class_='col-xs-6 mobile-normal')
        
        for schedule in scheduled:
           
            print("DateTimes; ", schedule.text.strip())
            for detail in details:
                print("Details:",  detail.text.strip())
```

but I receive the following output

[image: erroroutput2]

The output I am attempting to get is

[image: expectedoutput]

Thanks to anyone who can advise or provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip()` builtin function to "tie" the data together:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def makesoup(url):
    cookies = {'mycountries' : '101,28,3,102,42,10,18,4,2'}
    r = requests.post(url,  cookies=cookies)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")


def matchscrape(g_data):

    for match in g_data:
        scheduled = match.findAll('div', class_='main time col-sm-2 hidden-xs')
        details = match.findAll('div', class_='col-xs-6 mobile-normal')

        for s, d in zip(scheduled, details):  # <-- using zip() here!
            print(s.text.strip())
            print(d.text.strip())


def matches():
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://sport-tv-guide.live/live/darts")
    matchscrape(g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "listData"}))

matches()
```

Prints:

```
Darts 17:00
Simon Whitlock vs. Joyce Ryan
World Matchplay
Darts 18:00
Ratajski Krzysztof vs. Wattimena Jermaine
World Matchplay
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used this function before. So it is good to learn new things.